how to use a foreingkey field in a Multi-table inheritance?
Currently the code is working for me, however in admin panel it is not displaying the information in the fields. I assumed that the information that had been entered in the parent table would be seen in the child table, the inheritance table.
I can't use abstrac models because the parent table must be registered in the database and I can't use proxy since I can't add other fields
class Course(models.Model):
    
    CATEGORY = (
        ('Certificados Profesionales', 'Certificados Profesionales'),
        ('Cursos Autodirigidos', 'Cursos Autodirigidos'),
        ('Cursos Facilitados', 'Cursos Facilitados' ),
        ('Cursos Idiomas','Cursos Idiomas'),
        ('Cursos Interes General', 'Cursos Interes General'),
    )

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Identificador")

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Nombre")

    code = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Código")

    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, \
        verbose_name="Categoría", choices=CATEGORY, default='Cursos Interes General')

    credits = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0, \
        verbose_name="Créditos", db_default= 0)

    duration = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0, \
        verbose_name="Duración (horas)", db_default= 0)

    description = models.TextField(verbose_name="Descripción", null=False, \
        blank=False, help_text="Descripción del curso")

    prerequisite = models.TextField(null=True, blank=False, verbose_name="Prerrequisito", \
        default="No Aplica", help_text="Prerrequisito del curso")

    minumum_required = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=10, \
        verbose_name="Mínimo requerido")

    maximum_capacity = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=20, \
        verbose_name="Capacidad máxima")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} {self.code}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Curso"
        verbose_name_plural = "Cursos"
        ordering = ['name']

class Semester(models.Model):
    SEMESTER_CHOICES = [
        ('Ago', _('Agosto')),
        ('Ene' , _('Enero')),
        ('Ver', _('Verano')),
    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, verbose_name="Identificador")
    start_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Fecha de inicio")
    end_date = models.DateField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Fecha de finalización")
    semester = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=SEMESTER_CHOICES, verbose_name="Semestre")
    year = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, verbose_name="Año")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.semester} {self.year}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Semestre"
        verbose_name_plural = "Semestres"
        ordering = ['year', 'semester']

What I thought was that if I extended the course model, the values ​​that are inserted in course could have it with course4info and that would be seen in admin
class course4info(Course):
    semester = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Semestre")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Info Curso"
        verbose_name_plural = "Info Cursos"


Why not make a nullable field from Course to `semester?

Thanks for the suggestion, if you mean that in the course4info model I add a nullable field I cannot, or rather that is not what I want. I need it to be a foreign key. @willeM_VanOnsem

it can be a nullable foreignkey. Exactly what is the porpose of course4info otherwise: every course can now be a course4info thus linking to a single Semester, this is exactly what happens if you make it a nullable foreignkey in Course.

course4info is an intermediate table that I want to make where it joins the fields, name, code, max_students and min_students of Course as well as the semester field of Semester. My first option was to create a model whose fields were foreignkey but because the str function only allows me to return a string I cannot return name, code, max and min. What I am looking for is to create a table to make reports that takes information from different tables in the database and since I am using a type of export library that must be put in admin, the course4inform table must appear registered in admin

This one my first idea:                                                                                                   class CourseHistoryInform(models.Model):
course_name = models.ForeignKey(Course)
semester = models.ForeingKey(Semester)

Well then it is not a submodel, in fact it is not more than a junction table, so a ManyToManyField from Course to Semester.

Good morning, I ended up choosing to create a query and display the information in the html. Thank you very much for the advice since searching for what a junction table is, the solution appeared.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
